# Exception Handling (Easy Python)

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

```
user_input = int(input("Enter your number: "))
try:
    if user_input == str
def is_perfect(n):
    try:
        total = 0
        for x in range(1,n):
            if n % x == 0:
             total = total + x
        return total == n
    except NameError:
        print "Error"



print(is_perfect(user_input))
```

I'm having trouble with exception handling. I think its something pretty minor in my code that is breaking it.

This code takes a users input and outputs whether or not its a perfect number. When I test inputting a letter I still get a name error in the output.

Thank you!!!

Comment: This is not even valid Python code. You must be getting a syntax error instead of a `NameError`. Please post your actual code with the correct indentation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code is not well written. I reorganize the code and modify the error handling part.

**Update**: I put the printing in the `try` block to prevent the `NameError` exception.

Here is the new code:

```
def is_perfect(n):
    total = 0
    for x in range(1, n):
        if n % x == 0:
            total = total + x
    return total == n

if __name__ == '__main__':

    try:
        user_input = int(input("Enter your number: "))
        print(is_perfect(user_input))
    except ValueError:
        print("Error: enter a number")
```

> **Output**

```
Enter your number: 6
True
```

Comment: thank you! i am pretty new to the platform and I didn't know how to edit my code! i tried deleting a reposting but I was not able too, super sorry for how it looked :/. When doing try and except, is it better to implement them outside of functions?

Comment: Generally, you use `exception` whenever you need it (I mean whenever you want to prevent errors). Sometimes, it is possible to raise an exception on a part of the code and handling it in another part. You should read about *Exceptions in Python*...